# Don't bore/notch in middle third of a joist... span or member?

Tags: drill, joists, structural, building-regulations

Suppose I have a continuous joist supported somewhere in the middle. For ease let's say it's a 24 foot continuous joist, and there's a bearer right in the middle at the 12 foot mark.

Here's a picture I found online.

[image: Image found online]

I know I should not notch or bore in the middle 1/3 of the joist. Does a bearer make this joist two spans per this image?

Can I notch between 0'-4', 8'-16', and 20'-24'?

Or 0'-8' and 16'-24'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after a more thorough reading of the spec.

> R502.8.1 Sawn lumber. Notches in solid lumber joists, rafters and beams shall not exceed one-sixth of the depth of the
>   **member**, shall not be longer than one-third of the depth of the **member** and shall not be located in the middle one-third of
>   the **span**.

And it includes this very helpful graphic:

[image: picture]

So the answer is:

- A bearer **does** make a continuous joist into two spans.
- I can notch between 0'-4', 8'-16', and 20'-24'.